# Entity relationships with additional constraints

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities: Organization, Address, and Contact

- An Organization Can have Multiple Address.  (So the Address table has org_id as the FK)
- An Organization Can have Multiple Contact.  (So the Contact table has org_id as the FK)
- Each Contact can have multiple Addresses with the additional constraint that the address should belong to the same organization as the contact.

I defined Contact and Address to have a many to many relationship.  How can I restrict the XREF table to be limited to the same organization using doctrine?  I am currently handling it outside of doctrine on the app side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [class constraint validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) to ensure all addresses added to a contact come from the same organisation as the contact.